# Sci-fi movie involving a sex scene in a laboratory observation room

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have a scene in my head, but I don't remember the movie it is from. The scene features a woman and a man having enthusiastic sex in a laboratory observation room, while being observed by researchers or law enforcement types.

As best I can recall, the context is that the woman is either a humanoid alien or a human infected with a virus. Whatever the case, the symptom is that she has a nearly insatiable sexual appetite and eventually exhausts her male partner. Given the context, I suppose the movie genre is sci-fi or fantasy.

Thinking the scene might have been from *Lifeforce* or *Species* or *Splice*, I watched all of these movies recently. The scene isn't from any of them.

I concede it isn't much detail to work with, but it's all I can remember.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, do you happen to recall the woman's hair colour?

Comment: I have an abysmal sense of time, but it could have been 10 years ago or more when I saw the movie, and it could have been a Netflix DVD rental that was several years old at the time. I don't remember the woman's hair color specifically, but I'm partial to brunettes, so my hunch is that she had dark hair.

Comment: Might not be a movie? Showtime's Outer Limits for example  https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/Caught_in_the_Act

Comment: That Outer Limits episode has a similar concept to what I described (including the lovely brunette Alyssa Milano), but it's not what I'm searching for.

Comment: Was a part of the plot device a conversation between one of her former lovers and a shrink, who turns out to be of the same race?

Comment: I don't remember that specifically, but I wouldn't rule it out. What are you thinking @MauryMarkowitz?

Comment: @Kirby - I don't recall the name, but if it was the same one I would do a little more digging. The original source was a book from east of the Iron Curtain, I seem to recall it being Polish or Czech. It was made into a (somewhat short) movie around 1978 to 1982 era. But from your description that seems too early. The basic plot was that there was a woman working in a closed city and sleeping with scientists whose knowledge she would hoover. The "shrink" was trying to track her down. They both turn out to be aliens attempting to build a rocket to leave Earth.